# How I can return JSON Object when I using fetch API

Tags: javascript, json

I created Object, like this:

```
  var JSONRespond = new Respond('JS/lib/XML/options.json');
```

And I want raturn JSON Object to another Object, example:

```
var Options = JSONRespond.getOptions();
console.log("TEST" + Options.options[0].params) // doesn't working
```

Respond Class:

```
var Respond = function(URL){
this.requestURL = URL;
}

Respond.prototype.getOptions = function(){
    var JSON;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Method','GET');
    var request = new Request(this.requestURL, headers);
    fetch(request).then(function (response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(respondJSON){
        JSON = respondJSON;
        console.log("Test respondJSON:" + respondJSON.options[1].params); //OK
        console.log("Test JSON:" + JSON.options[0].params); // ok too
        return JSON; //
        })

    }
```

How I get JSON Object and return main function?(dont using promises, callback).

Comment: How are you expecting to get the result of an asynchronous operation without using callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

Since getOptions returns nothing itsself, the JSON you return from the last 'then' just disappears. You probably want to return the promise and chain another 'then' after it. Something similar to:

```
Respond.prototype.getOptions = function(){
    ...
    return fetch(request)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        });
};

var JSONRespond = new Respond('JS/lib/XML/options.json');
var Options = JSONRespond.getOptions();
Options.then(function( JSON ) {
    console.log(JSON);
});
```

Note: What do you mean with '(dont using promises, callback)' ?
You could call getOptions providing a callback and then call that callback in your last 'then'.

Comment: Sry, I forgot I can use promises to main function ^^. What I mean? I was thinking , I don't able to return "main" thread. So, don't like see like this: t